# Jest mock knex fn.now(), but keep rest of implementation

Tags: jestjs, knex.js

I am writing tests for a service that uses knex, however, since the knex calls has several uses of knex.fn.now() my tests will produce varied results over time. I'm wondering if it's possible to mock/spy/hijack the inner calls to knex.fn.now() to something I can control, while letting the rest of the code stay in its 'real' implementation. I can only find examples of mocking knex completely which would make the purpose of my testing pointless.

So I'm wondering if it's possible to have jest listen for a specific function call and insert another value in it's stead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock Knex package by creating a folder `__mocks__/knex/index.js`.

Inside this file u can require the real knex implementation, change it, and export.

It should look something like this:

```js
// __mocks__/knex/index.js
const knex = require('knex');

const fixedTime = new Date();
knex.fn.now = () => fixedTime;

module.exports = knex;
```